# Filter element based on property's list bash/jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

Given the List:

```
[
    {
        "prop1": "prop11",
        "prop2": "prop21",
        "list": ["element1", "element2", "element3"]
    },
    {
        "prop1": "prop12",
        "prop2": "prop22",
        "list": ["element1", "element3"]
    },
    {
        "prop1": "prop13",
        "prop2": "prop23",
        "list": ["element2", "element3"]
    }
]
```

While using jq, how to filter only the root's list elements by the children's lists.
For example, return all elements whose list contains element1. The output should be:

```
[
    {
        "prop1": "prop11",
        "prop2": "prop21",
        "list": ["element1", "element2", "element3"]
    },
    {
        "prop1": "prop12",
        "prop2": "prop22",
        "list": ["element1", "element3"]
    }
]
```

or

```
{"prop1": "prop11","prop2": "prop21","list": ["element1", "element2", "element3"]}
{"prop1": "prop12","prop2": "prop22","list": ["element1", "element3"]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `any` of the list's element equals `==` the given string:

```bash
jq 'map(select(any(.list[]; . == "element1")))'
```

```json
[
  {
    "prop1": "prop11",
    "prop2": "prop21",
    "list": [
      "element1",
      "element2",
      "element3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "prop1": "prop12",
    "prop2": "prop22",
    "list": [
      "element1",
      "element3"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_x11qEVoSoi)

---

Use `.[] | …` instead of `map(…)` to get rid of the outer array:

```bash
jq '.[] | select(any(.list[]; . == "element1"))'
```

```json
{
  "prop1": "prop11",
  "prop2": "prop21",
  "list": [
    "element1",
    "element2",
    "element3"
  ]
}
{
  "prop1": "prop12",
  "prop2": "prop22",
  "list": [
    "element1",
    "element3"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JLhtx9tJty4)

Answer (score 3):

`index` makes for a short and in practice quite fast solution:

```
jq 'map(select(.list|index("element1")))'
```

or

```
jq -c '.[] | select(.list|index("element1"))'
```